# How can I compare a sample and population from three percentage groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, t-test

I have data from a national poll whereby three questions were answered with either "Do" "Do not" or "Not sure." I have conducted a random sample poll at my school with the same three questions and three responses, sampling from my entire grade. Say for one question, the national results are 70% Do, 20% Do not, and 10% Not sure...while for my sample, the same question has average response 35% Do, 40% Do not, and 25% Not sure. How can I conduct a significance test to measure whether the responses from my sample are different (statistically speaking) from the population (national) average for one particular question?

I suspect a t-test or chi-squared test would be adequate, but I don't know how to implement it for this scenario.